# Run of a next js app stucked, npm run dev doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, npm, next.js

When I created a simple next.js app, and started it with `npm run dev`, it worked. When I tried it to start a second time, it was stuck:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ce3hT.png)

I tried to create a new project... the same scenario.

Other React apps (without Next.js) are working correctly.

Do you have any ideas on how to fix it, please?

Thanks.

I tried restart PC, "kill" Node process.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It sounds like a corruption in Next.js. Here's a few possible solutions:

## 1. Delete the `.next` folder

Sometimes the `.next` folder can become corrupted resulting in errors like this.

a. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to kill the terminal

b. Delete the `.next` folder

c. Run the command `npm run dev` and give it time as the `.next` folder is rebuilt and runs the app

## 2. Reinstall all dependencies

If the first method doesn't work then you can conclude the `.next` folder is likely not the problem. The issue could be corrupted dependencies.

a. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to kill the terminal

b. Delete `node_modules`

c. Run the command `npm install` to reinstall all the dependencies

## 3. Clear Node.js cache

It's possible that Node has cached corrupted files.

a. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to kill the terminal

b. Run the command `npm cache clean --force`

## 4. Repair the Node.js installation

If the above is working or the command cannot run do to NPM being frozen you can try repairing the Node.js installation.

a. Open file explorer

b. Navigate to downloads

c. Open Node.js installer

d. In the popup that will appear select "repair"

## Edit: 5. Update Node.js

*I would recomend this before trying next@canary*

a. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to kill the terminal

b. Go to where ever your Node installation is and uninstall it

c. Go to [nodejs.org](https://nodejs.org) to install the latest version of Node. Check out [this article for how to choose between LTS and current](https://medium.com/@asiandigitalhub/node-js-lts-vs-current-which-version-to-choose-a470467eb62e#:%7E:text=For%20production%20environments%20where%20stability,want%20to%20explore%20new%20functionalities.)

d. After installing, re-run `npm run dev`

## 6. Install Next.js canary *(formaly #5)*

If none of this works install the canary version of Next.js. This is a version of Next.js released daily with bug fixes not yet in the stable version of Next.js.

a. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to kill the terminal

b. Run the command `npm install next@canary`

If all else fails it's likely a bug in Next.js. I would recommend opening a Github issue that way the problem gets fixed ASAP.

Comment: Thank you a lot. The first solution is working. You are amazing :).

Comment: Step 2 worked for me. I had previously done the `npm install` using node 20+ and forgotten about it. Later I was trying to do the `npm run dev` on node 18.* and it was just quitting without any error. Deleting `node_modules`, installing and running again worked.

Answer (score 1):

1. Uninstall `nodejs`
2. Download recommended version.

Tried deleting `.next` folder, removing the `node modules` and reinstalling but it didn't work. This seemed to work for me

Answer (score 0):

If your app uses TypeScript, you could try running `npm run type-check`, and then fixing the errors that are displayed. It helped for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me the only fix was to add the following in the `next.config.mjs`:

```js
 const nextConfig = {
        webpack: function (config, context) {
        config.watchOptions = {
            poll: 1000,
            aggregateTimeout: 300,
        };
        return config;
    },
};
```