# How can i get this nextJS app to stop trying to use an old version of node that I don't have installed?

Tags: reactjs, npm, next.js

Starting a nextjs project, after running `npx create-next-app@latest` trying to start the project with `npm run dev` but failing. I've spent time reading relevant posts and have attempted all methods. Eg) full wipe of node/nvm from OS, using NVM.
Getting this during the build: [wrong node version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTjRg.png)

Spun up a new vite app and opened some previous next.js projects without issue.

- Full node wipe, and install from website dl to 20.10.0 so i don't see why it's pointing to v16.14.2 for some reason. I've tried using NVM to uninstall all other versions and set the default as well, still the same error as above. npx and npm both in the /bin appropriately.
- Trying `npm i node @lts` within the project as suggested throws this: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKmYL.png)
- Tried removing next folder, node_modules and cache clean with full reinstall of packages (did not do canary install yet) in this post [text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77232531/run-of-a-next-js-app-stucked-npm-run-dev-doesnt-work)

Any suggestions on why it's trying to default to this version that I no longer have on my machine, or how to fix?

Comment: Did you update the node version in the package.json file and reinstall the node_modules and package-lock.json file?

Comment: You seem to be mixing up `nvm` and `npm`, unless that's a typo in your post. `nvm i node @lts` will work provided nvm is installed

Answer (score -1):

go to the terminal and type

```
node -version //This will give you the current node version, in your case update version
```

then go to the next js project and find package.json file. Here you need to replace the old node version with the current node version

```
"node": ">=20.10.0"
```

Delete the node_modules and package-lock.json files then go to the terminal and reinstall dependencies

```
npm install
```

Comment: For some reason the node dependency wasn't being added to the project package.json at all, so manually added it and working fine now. Your answer led me to review the package.json again to find the issue, thanks

Comment: It won't and shouldn't be added to your project `package.json`. Because node isn't a dependency of your project. If it's a dependency of next it goes in *that* project's `package.json`, which you don't and shouldn't manage.

Answer (score -1):

Unclear on the causation, but node dependency not added to package.json, when  using auto or manual Next.js install methodologies from terminal. Solved by manually adding Node dependency to package.json file of project.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).